# CTDB and SAMBA Cluster

Tags: samba, rhel7

I am trying to setup Samba Cluster with CTDB on CentOS7. I am having some confusion about how CTDB work with SAMBA. Here are my queries -

1) How to disable CTDB IP Failback?
When node1 die, node2 will take over public IP using CTDB. When node1 is fixed and booted, node1 takes over public IP from node2 which cause unnecessary downtime again. I tried adding CTDB_Set_NoIPFailback=1 in /etc/sysconfig/ctdb, but it doesn't work. Help will be appreciated.

2) Can CTDB handle samba users database?
Now whenever I want to add a user or change password for a user in samba/ctdb cluster, I have to do so twice for both node using smbpasswd command. Is CTDB supposed to handle it? Or Am I doing it wrongly?
By the way I got cluster filesystem in place. (GFS2)

Thanks in advance,